# Auto increment considering Tenant id

Tags: sql-server, triggers, auto-increment, calculated-columns

I'm using SQL Server and need to keep an accounting number with reference to the tenant id.

I cannot use the auto increment id because it is sequentially increments and has gaps in the client applications.

I couldn't use computed columns as aggregate functions like `Max` is not allowed

[image]

What would be the best approach for this?

Comment: Use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TenantID ORDER BY ID ASC)`

Comment: @ M.Ali this is for select queries or views right?
I want to add the column to the table.

Comment: Curious why you can't use Max?  As you're inserting your record PaymentId = (SELECT Max(PaymentId) + 1 FROM Table WHERE TenantId = @tenantId).  

Also, as a slight recommendation, if PaymentId isn't joining to another table I would simply call it PaymentNumber (Id implies a primary key to another table).

Comment: @BlackjacketMack +1 for the naming suggestion.
Are you suggesting to use a trigger?
I was trying to add it as a computed column..

Comment: A trigger would work but I tend to steer away from triggers because they're hard to maintain (keep in source control, identify etc.).  But an after-trigger would certainly work as would a transactional update (run right after inserting a record).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also can process when insert data, For example:

```
insert into table1(ID,TenantId,PaymentId)
select 6,2,isnull(max(PaymentId)+1,1)
from table1 where TenantId=2 
group by TenantId
```

If you want to use trigger,This is a sample, In ths sample, even you specify a PaymentId when inserting data, this trigger also recalculating the PaymentId

```
    DROP TABLE table1
    CREATE TABLE Table1(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),TenantId INT ,PaymentId INT)

    CREATE TRIGGER trg_UpdatePaymentId 
       ON  dbo.TABLE1
       AFTER INSERT
    AS 
    BEGIN

        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        UPDATE t SET t.PaymentId=a.rn
        FROM dbo.TABLE1 AS t INNER JOIN (
            SELECT i.ID,(ISNULL(c.MaxPaymentId,0)+ ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY TenantId ORDER BY ID)) AS rn FROM Inserted AS i
            OUTER APPLY(
                SELECT MAX(tt.PaymentId) AS MaxPaymentId FROM Table1 AS tt WHERE tt.TenantId=i.TenantId AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 0 FROM Inserted AS ii WHERE ii.ID=tt.ID)
            ) AS c
        ) AS a ON a.ID=t.ID 


    END
    GO


    INSERT INTO table1(TenantId)VALUES(1),(2),(1),(1)
    SELECT * FROM dbo.TABLE1
```

```
ID          TenantId    PaymentId
----------- ----------- -----------
1           1           1
2           2           1
3           1           2
4           1           3
```

Comment: Need the fix in table level as I'm using .Net Entity framework to add data.

Comment: @PAVITRA  I give you a trigger sample.