# Auto increment considering Tenant id in existing table

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables Tenants and Inovices. Invoices have tenant_id column, and I need to add invoice_number incremental field by tentan_id to table Invoices.

My problem is identical to this [Auto increment considering Tenant id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41336686/auto-increment-considering-tenant-id)

Actually, this solution works for me, but now I need to fill the invoice_number increment field of existing rows on table before apply the trigger in this solution.

Something like this but incrementing by tenant_id:

```
DECLARE @invoice_number INT 
SET @@invoice_number = 0 
UPDATE Invoices
SET @invoice_number = invoice_number = @invoice_number + 1 
GO
```

How to loop and increment by each tenant?

Answer (score 0):

You might use  the following solution

- Add a column `invoice_seq` in your `Tenants` table, so your `Tenants` table should look like `Tenants(tenant_id,name,...,invoice_seq)`, so on creating the invoice, you do the following steps

  1. Increment the `invoice_seq` in table `InvoiceTenants`
  2. update the `Invoice` record by setting the `invoice_number ='I' format(tenant_id,'000') + '-' + format(invoice_seq,'000000')`

Here your invoice number will look like:

```
I001-000001 <-- tenant 1 and sequence 1
I001-000002
I001-000003 <-- tenant 1 and sequence 3
I002-000001 <-- tenant 2 and sequence 1
I003-000001 <-- tenant 3 and sequence 1
```

** sample code **

-- for the example below i will user @tenant = 1, the below code can be converted to stored procedure of code behind in your application

```
declare @invoice_seq int,
        @tenant int = 1 -- here you can change the number to the way you wish

-- retrieve the last tenant +1

select @invoice_seq = invoice_seq+1 from Tenants where tenant_id=@tenant

-- add the invoice

insert into Invoices(tenant_id,invoice_number,... other columns....)
values (@tenant,'I' + format(@tenant,'000') + '-' + format(@invoice_seq,'000000'),... other columns...)

-- update the invoice_seq in the Tenants table

update Tenants set invoice_seq = @invoice_seq where tenant_id=@tenant
```

Hope this will help you